# laravel 10 install, debugbar auto discovery

Tags: php, laravel-10, autodiscovery

Years ago, I installed laravel for a small project. Now I'm installing a brand new laravel, but it's a small struggle with the auto discovery.

I used this as a reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos

first executing the install

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

then starting it up:

```
cd example-app
/vendor/bin/sail up
```

at this point, I see the beginpage when entering `localhost` in my browser

Next I try to install the debugbar https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

First I opened another terminal, using CD I went to the correct location until **example-app** was my folder. Executed the next line:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev
```

I also copied the config file

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"
```

As far as I understand the debugbar manual, this is all what needs to be done. In .env, APP_DEBUG=true , so this is normally oké to show the debugbar I guess?

When I do a refresh on my `localhost` in my browser, the debugbar is nog showing.

When I enter `composer install` , I have a list of 8 `discovering packages`, which includes the debugbar. After this command, still the debugbar is not showing.

Also did `composer dump-autoload`, a command I've seen in another post, but also no progress

anyone knows what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted sail?

Comment: In fact, that did the trick, did not know this could be an issue. I guess it would all work when I first installed laravel, then debugbar, and then doing sail up

Answer (score 1):

Check the Error of laravel app In Storage Folder.
Issue May be regarding The version Compatibility (Php Version and Laravel Version).
Also Try To Install laravel Via Composer It will install your fresh laravel app according to your exiting platform.

**Command :** composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app

For the above command first download composer and install from https://getcomposer.org/